# SSRS filtering using Parameters and Dataset values

Tags: reporting-services, filter, parameters

I have a report that when run produces a list of numbers based upon a parameter which signifies year. For instance I choose 2019 on the parameter, numbers 1 - 10 come out in rows with additional columns based on that. What I want to do it select 2018 and have it only show 1-7 and 10, thus removing 8 and 9 but when i select say 2019 it shows all 10 rows again.

Any ideas how I can do this under the filter option in group properties? The group is on the field that has the numbers in, several rows per number initially show, thus grouping on the numbers creates one row per number.

Parameter 2019:

E1001  1   Tom
E1002  2   Rob
E1003  3   Ben

Parameter 2018:

E1001  1   Tom
E1003  3   Ben

Comment: What other columns are there? Do you have a date column? Are you able to filter in the SQL query? Sample data and expected result would help.

Comment: Period, Region, CSSR, Employees, Jobrole, Vacancies

Comes out like this:

E1247      1          Tom
E1231      2          Rob
E2473      3          Ben

Comment: If you are only going to be using those years then you can just have a visibility expression for the group.